# How to exclude worksheets with "- Matrix" at the end of their name?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which I want to apply on multiple worksheets.
I want to exclude "Data" and all the worksheets containing "- Matrix".
I used * wildcard to select these worksheets though it doesn't work.

```
Sub DoForSheets()
    Dim xwks As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xwks In Worksheets
        If xwks.Name <> "Data" And xwks.Name <> "* - Matrix" Then
           Debug.Print xwks.Name
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `and not xwks.name like "*- Matrix"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Instr` will do the Job for you.

**Try:**

```
Sub DoForSheets()

    Dim xwks As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xwks In Worksheets
        If xwks.Name <> "Data" And Not InStr(1, xwks.Name, "- Matrix") > 0 Then
           Debug.Print xwks.Name
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Doesn't Matter where the `- Matrix` is in the Name. This will not Fail

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Right`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/right-function) function:

```
 Right(xwks.Name, 6) = "Matrix" 'returns True if right hand side of the string is "Matrix"
```

There is also [`Left`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/left-function) and  [`Mid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mid-function)